# How to use PHP regular expressions to search a string for word sequences containing repeated words?

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP to count the number of occurrences of a word sequence in a string. In the following example cases, I am not getting the result I would like to see.

```
$subject1 = " [word1 [word1 [word1 [word1 [word3 ";
$pattern1 = preg_quote("[word1 [word1", '/');
echo "count of '[word1 [word1'=". preg_match_all("/(\s|^|\W)" . $pattern1 . "(?=\s|$|\W)/", $subject1, $dummy) . "<br/>"; 

$subject2 = " [word1 [word2 [word1 [word2 [word1 [helloagain ";
$pattern2 = preg_quote("[word1 [word2 [word1", '/');
echo "count of '[word1 [word2 [word1'=". preg_match_all("/(\s|^|\W)" . $pattern2 . "(?=\s|$|\W)/", $subject2, $dummy) . "<br/>";
```

the above returns:

```
count of '[word1 [word1'=2
count of '[word1 [word2 [word1'=1
```

I would like the result to be:

```
count of '[word1 [word1'=3 // there are 3  instances of ‘[word1 [word1’ in $subject1
count of '[word1 [word2 [word1'=2 // // there are 2  instances of [word1 [word2 [word1’ in $subject2
```

One way to achieve this is each time the pattern is found in subject the next search should start from the *second* word in the matched substring. Can such a regular expression be constructed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of preg_match_all, I'd use a while loop on preg_match with offset:

```
$subject1 = " [word1 [word1 [word1 [word1 [word3 ";
$pattern1 = preg_quote("[word1 [word1", '/');
$offset=0;
$total=0;
while($count = preg_match("/(?:\s|^|\W)$pattern1(?=\s|$|\W)/", $subject1, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)) {
    // summ all matches
    $total  += $count;
    // valorisation of offset with the position of the match + 1
    // the next preg_match will start at this position
    $offset  = $matches[0][1]+1;
}
echo "total=$total\n";
```

**output:**

```
total=3
```

The result for the second example is : `total=2`

Comment: Thanks a lot M42, it does what I wanted.

Comment: Monir correction to M42’s code:
`$offset += $matches[0][1]+1;` should be `$offset = $matches[0][1]+1;`
otherwise the correct result is not found in all cases such as this one: `$subject1 = " This is another string [word1 [word1 [word1 [word1 [word3 ";` `$pattern1 = preg_quote("[word1 [word1", '/');`

Answer (score 1):

Use [mb_substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr-count.php)

`substr_count` does not count overlapped values, but i dont know why, `mb_substr_count` does

```
$subject1 = " [word1 [word1 [word1 [word1 [word3 ";
echo mb_substr_count($subject1, "[word1 [word1"); // 3
echo mb_substr_count($subject1, "[word1 [word1 [word1"); // 2
```

**EDIT:**

For future reference,

Apparently `mb_substr_count` acts differently on php 5.2 than php 5.3 . I suppose the right behavior of this function should be same as `substr_count`, only for multibyte support, and since `substr_count` doesn't support overlapping, so should  `mb_substr_count`.

So, though this answer works on php 5.2.6, do not use it, or you may have problems when you update your php version.

Comment: mb_substr_count() returns the same results as my own code :-(

Comment: what is your php version. mine is 5.2.6